# Получить матрицу UIElement объекта

Tags: wpf, .net, c++-cli

Каким способом можно получить матрицу визуального объекта кроме данного:

```
Matrix matrix = ((Transform^)TransformToVisual(Parent))->Value;
```

Матрица нужна для отрисовки невидимой области, а точнее ее заполнения черным цветом при масштабировании видео.

Comment: А что такое «матрица визуального объекта»?

Comment: @VladD: Ну к примеру когда вы изменяете размер объекта, или двигаете его, оригинальная матрица объекта не меняется, а его offsett'ы получают отрицательное или положительное значение. Имеется ввиду только тот факт когда вы переопределяте методы `MeassureArrange` и ему подобные

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Откуда-то ещё взялись оффсеты и переопределение `MeassureArrange` (вы имели в виду, наверное, `MeasureOverride` и `ArrangeOverride`?)

Comment: @VladD: Да-да именно их я и имел ввиду :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел в классе `VisualTreeHelper` метод `GetOffset` возвращающий вектор отступов которые необходимы.

```
VisualTreeHelper::GetOffset(this);
```